# How can dynamic hyperlinks be added in InfoPath form?

Tags: c#, infopath

How can I add a dynamic hyperlink on an `InfoPath` form? I would like to do this from a C# code-behind.

Anyone help me, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The destination of the hyperlink can be stored in a field in the datasource so you can just change the value in that field.  I could add a picture but the site will not let me

Answer (score 0):

You can't very easily. Unfortunately hyperlinks are not controls in InfoPath so it is not as easy as just changing the URL using a property.

The best workaround I have found is to use a button control (which you can code behind using the click event) and change the formatting so it looks like a hyperlink (remove the border and background color and change the font). The only drawback to this method is your users won't get the "hand" mouse pointer when they roll over the button so you need to make it obvious that it is a link.